# Server admin but can't get into Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to help a server admin grant me access to a TFS project as a developer, but we're getting error messages as we go.

I've been made a local administrator on the server where TFS resides, but when I attempt to go into the TFS console to grant myself rights as a developer, I'm getting the included error display, below:

[image]

How do I give myself the appropriate permissions to administer TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should check here:

1. Make sure you are running the console as administrator.
2. Make sure you have permissions to directly talk to SQL.  This is usually set through the security folder in SQL Server Management Studio.  You will need read/write privileges to the Tfs_Configuration database and all of the collection databases.

2 is likely your problem given the error messages that are being shown.

Comment: The TFS account, itself, has been lost to us.  Our server techs are working with Microsoft to first recover access to the SQL server, and then back into a freshly-authenticated TFS account from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the SQL Services (from the SQL Configuration Manager) are all running under the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.

Looks like it's not the case. If it is that mean the account you used to run the TFS Administration Console is not an administrator of the TFS Server.

If you following the setup procedure you should have:

1. Everything installed with a given account (typically TFSSETUP), member of the domain and member of the Adminigrators group of the Computer.
2. NETWORK SERVICE account for SQL Service.
3. IIS Web App Pool and TFS Services account can be run with NETWORK SERVICE or a domain service account (typically named TFSSERVICE).

Do you know what kind configuration was used to installed TFS ? Standard, Custom ?